# Temperature Calculation Code Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will print out the temperature in Fahrenheit. My goal is to not use any condition like the `if` statement or any loops.

```
public class TemperatureConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        double celsius, fahrenheit; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.print("Enter the temperature in degrees Celsius:  "); 
        fahrenheit = input.nextDouble(); 
        celsius = 5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32); 

        System.out.printf(+celsius, "degrees Celsius is" +fahrenheit "degrees Fahrenheit"); 
    }
}
```

I am getting an error which is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method printf(String, Object...) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (double, String)
Syntax error on token ""degrees Fahrenheit"", delete this token

at TemperatureConverter.main(TemperatureConverter.java:14)
```

Edit:

I am not coming up with what I need to come up with. When I run this program the output is this:

For this example the user inputted 45 for the prompt of Celsius.

> Enter the temperature in degrees Celsius: 45
>   42.77777777777778 degrees Celsius is 45.0 degrees Fahrenheit

Comment: printf doesn't accept those parameters, have a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Comment: This is not the correct arguments for printf, the first parameter has to be of type String and it should define the conversion patterns for the arguments. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: @StackOverflowException there's no homework tag, it got axed about a year ago.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it doesn't exist anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Well just to fix your error:

```
System.out.print(celsius + "degrees Celsius is " + fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit");
```

or you could do this if you want to use `printf`.

```
System.out.printf("%f degrees Celsius is %f degrees Fahrenheit",celsius,fahrenheit);
```

---

The reason I did all this is mainly just simple syntax. Strings are stuff within double quotes. `"blah"` for example is a String containing the word `blah`.

If you want to concatenate two strings then you use the `+` operator in Java. So you want to add `"foo"` and `"bar"` you write `"foo" + "bar"` and you get `"foobar"`.

In your attempt you have made two errors:

Firstly, (the intention of) string concatenation was done wrong. `+ celsius` isn't a syntax error because celsius is a number but if it were a string then the compiler doesnt have anythign to the left of that `+` to concatenate the value of celsius with. `"" + celsius` would have been fine if you wanted to prepend nothing.

`+ celsius` effectively does nothing since it is a number. Positive or negative wont matter. `-celsius` of course flips the sign. If you want to display a positive number always (although your output would then be incorrect) you can use Math.abs(celsius).

Secondly, since you are using `System.out.printf` there is a specific format that you need to follow. i.e. the first argument must be a string (possibly with things like %d, %f, %s, etc) which the function will replace with the subsequent arguments that you provide it.

This is what my solution does, it uses `%f` (for floating point numbers) twice and I give it two things `celsius` and `fahrenheit` which are doubles and Java realizes that all is good and just replaces the values in there. You can use things like `%.2f` if you wanted two decimal places and such as well, this is the advantage of printf over a normal print or println (print + new line).

---

To fix the real other problem is that you are taking in temprature in celsius but saving it to the variable fahrenheit. If you just change that then all will be well.

```
System.out.print("Enter the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit:  ");
```

Comment: Could you please specify what he did wrong and how you solved it? The man with the fish for a lifetime thing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Sidenote though: `println(+celsius + "something");` won't cause an error because `celsius` is a double and the `+` gets interpreted as 'positive' <number>, not 'concatenate' <number>.

Comment: Grrr. True! celsius isn't a string.

Answer (score 0):

To print output use:

```
System.out.println(celsius + "degrees Celsius is" + fahrenheit + "degrees Fahrenheit");
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%f degrees Celsius is %f degrees Fahrenheit",celsius,fahrenheit);
```

**[EDIT]** what went wrong.

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method printf(String, Object...)
```

- As the error says your syntax for `printf()` is wrong please refer [link](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/csc2010/f13/assignments/h4/printf.pdf)

Comment: Could you please specify what he did wrong and how you solved it? The man with the fish for a lifetime thing.

Comment: 1/ Syntax of printf is wrong

2/ + is concatenation operator for string

Answer (score 0):

Try considering this print statement:

```
 System.out.println(celsius+" is degrees Celsius and " +fahrenheit+ " is degrees Fahrenheit");
```

Answer (score 0):

To start off, you are asking the user to enter the temperature in celcius and then assigning that value to a variable called fahrenheit. It doesn't seem to be very appropriate. As some other have said you aren't constructing the String correctly.

I have tidied up you code and changed the variable names as well as the formula to calculate the degrees in Fahrenheit.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        double celsius, fahrenheit; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature in degrees Celsius:  "); 
        celsius = input.nextDouble(); 
        fahrenheit = celsius*9.0/5.0 + 32; 

        System.out.print(celsius + " degrees Celsius is " + fahrenheit+  " degrees Fahrenheit"); 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    System.out.printf(+celsius, "degrees Celsius is" +fahrenheit "degrees Fahrenheit"); 

Check your original statement. You have missed adding one +(append) to add strings.

Use this 

   System.out.printf("%f degrees Celsius is %f degrees Fahrenheit",celsius,fahrenheit);
```

Comment: This will result in the exact same compilation error as before.

Comment: @StackOverflowException Post got edit with that.didn't get can you help??

Comment: @csmckelvey what's the issue then..?

Comment: I just changed your formatting so your text wasn't appearing as code, didn't change your answer. The issue is that you are using `printf()` without providing any of the formatting parameters. You have made the exact same mistake that is in the original question.